# Does "/proc/{pid}/reclaim" not used in current Android source code?

Tags: android, android-source

Linux kernel has a feature to reclaim process memory by writing `1/2/3` to `/proc/{pid}/reclaim` as https://lwn.net/Articles/548431/. but when I check current Android  source code, it not exist. So I am wondering if such feature has deprected or moved?

Comment: "So I am wondering if such feature has deprected or moved?" - As far as I understand, the feature `/proc/pid/reclaim` was never be included into the mainline kernel. The article you refer to is dated with 2013 and it was the first attempt to suggest the patch with that functionality. The second attempt was 3 years later: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1465804259-29345-1-git-send-email-minchan@kernel.org/, and I have found no evidence that it was accepted.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your comment, I think I misunderstood this. I found this api was used in Android framework, but in current codes, I found `process_mdadvice` is used,  I will checking this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think I found the reason from the commit message:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/1730078

```sh
Edgar Arriaga  Edgar Arriaga, a year ago   (August 13th, 2020 4:03am) 

Migrate to use process_madvise syscall instead of procfs interface for memory compaction

Currently the system uses procfs and we are migrating to use a syscall called process_madvise
which makes the code upstreamable and will allow for making compaction widely available for multiple
android devices.

It also opens room for future developments that involve a finer grain VMA compressions
than the current procfs allows.
```